# How to set cargo unstable options for a target?

Tags: rust, config, rust-cargo

I have `.cargo/config.toml` with following:

```ini
[unstable]
unstable-options = true
build-std = ["core", "alloc"]
```

But I need `build-std` only for one target (e.g. `thumbv7em-none-eabihf`).

Is there any way to **declare it specifically for a target?**

It could be something like this:

```ini
# wrong example, doesn't work apparently
[target.thumbv7em-none-eabihf.unstable]
build-std = ["core", "alloc"]
```

Note, I’m talking about configs only, I know how to configure it with cargo execution arguments. That’s needed to automatically ignore `build-std` for targets other then mentioned, e.g. default host target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 2023-07-04 this is not possible to achieve using only the built-in cargo configuration. See the Background section for details.

## Workaround

You will need to build with an external invocation of cargo for that target e.g. for "core" and "alloc"

```bash
cargo build --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf -Z build-std="core,alloc"
```

Tested with the relevant toolchain installed and this test program:

```rust
#![feature(restricted_std)]

fn main() {
    loop {}
}
```

with cargo invocation

```bash
cargo build --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf -Z build-std="std,panic_abort"
```

## Background

After some experimentation and searching, there is an open issue for cargo to add this feature [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8733) but progress appears to be slow as multiple different approaches have been explored. As build-std is still an unstable interface, available only in nightly versions of cargo, there are still [conflicts with other features](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/9451) and some [open](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/10330) as well as [closed](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/10308) PRs related to changing the semantics. The tracking issue for this kind of feature is [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/wg-cargo-std-aware/issues/43).

Comment: Unfortunately, sims to that isn’t a solution, because Im talking about configs only, I know how to configure it with cargo execution arguments. It needed to automatically ignore `build-std` for targets other Then mentioned, e.g. default host target.